# JavaScript regex check line break

Tags: javascript, regex

I get information from a database that includes Locker code and is dependent on the orderId. Some orders have a Locker code, which is used to unlock the door when customers pick up their orders from locker storage.

If the locker exist then it will show in UI like this:

```js
Locker code: // this is one html div


123456 // and the code is in another div which is string
```

I used regex to test the locker code in E2E testing. That regex will match the string "Locker code" and six digits . For that regex match I did like this `expect(body).toMatch(/Locker code: [\r\n]+ \[A-Z0-9]+/)`. But seems like regex match does not work. I believe it is due to the "Locker code" and the use of a 6-digit number string in two different divs. But I can't say I'm certain. Is there any better way I can test "Locker code" and six digits?

Comment: Could you please edit your question by adding the value of the `body` that is used at `expect(body)`

Comment: Body is in code snippet.

Comment: `// this is one html div` also part of the body or you wanted to describe something?

Comment: Yes. if the Locker exist. then in UI it should like this: <div><h1>Locker code:</h1></div>  <div><h1>12345</h1></div>.

Comment: So `body` is the `innerText` of the `<div><h1>Locker code:</h1></div> <div><h1>12345</h1></div>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to

```
^.*?Lokerokoodisi on:.*?\d{6}.*$
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6nRSFx/1)

```js
expect(body).toMatch(/^.*?Lokerokoodisi on:.*?\d{6}.*$/)
```

Comment: I tried like this:  `expect(body).toMatch(^Locker code:.*?\n+\d{6}.*$)` but seems like syntax issue

Comment: You should try: `expect(body).toMatch(/^Locker code:.*?\n+\d{6}.*$/)`

Comment: @Krisna, did you try? This solution expects the body look like the text in the above code snippet.

Comment: It still failed . I am not sure what's wrong in this test.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the value of the `body`. Could you please comment on this answer the result of the `console.log(body)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245660/discussion-between-krisna-and-artyom-vancyan).